# Using View Localization in ASP.NET Core

Tags: localization, resources, asp.net-core-1.1

I want to use localization in an ASP.NET Core applciation that uses Areas.

I have got a partial view Areas\Admin\Views\People\GetPeopleStatistics.cshtml

In this I want to use localiuation:

```
...
@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer

<h3>@Localizer["People Statistics"]:</h3>
...
```

I created a resource file for this: Resources\Admin\Views\People\GetPeopleStatistics.en.resx

I have the following configuration in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddLocalization(opts => { opts.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; });
        services.AddMvc()
            .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix, opts => { opts.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; })
            .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
        services.AddAutoMapper();

        services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(
            opts =>
            {
                var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
                {
                    new CultureInfo("en"),
                    new CultureInfo("de")
                };

                opts.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en");
                // Formatting numbers, dates, etc.
                opts.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
                // UI strings that we have localized.
                opts.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
            });
```

Unfortunatelly this does not work. The application does not display the value from the resource file.

I am using Cookies to store the culture:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task SetLanguage(string culture)
    {
        Response.Cookies.Append(
            CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
            CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(culture)),
            new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(1) }
        );
    }
```

I also get the following error in Visual Studio:

```
Custom tool PublicResXFileCodeGenerator failed to produce an output for input file 'Resources\Admin\Views\People\GetPeopleStatistics.en.resx' but did not log a specific error. WebApplication  D:\SVN Repositories\SRMS\trunk\PresentationLayer\WebApplication\Resources\Admin\Views\People\GetPeopleStatistics.en.resx    1
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I configure this?

Answer (score 0):

You might want try the following: rightclick your solution and do 'clean solution'. That solved the issue for me when localization was not working and I was 100% sure everything was configured correctly.